# Ajax Contact Form Loader issue

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
 var dataString = 'name=' + $("input#name").val() + '&email=' + $("input#email").val() + '&comments=' + $("textarea#comments").val();
                $('#reply_message').addClass('email_loading');

                // Send form data 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "SendMail",
                    data: dataString,

                    success: function () {

                        $('#reply_message').removeClass('email_loading');
                        $('#reply_message').addClass('list3');
                        $('#reply_message').html("Mail sent sucessfully");
                        $('#reply_message').delay(500).fadeOut(3500);
                        $("input#name").val('Name');
                        $("input#email").val('Email');
                        $("textarea#comments").val('Comments..');

                    }

                });


                return false;

            });


        });
```

This is my ajax script for sending an email everything is working fine for the first time user is filling the form and submitting but if user is filling form again and click on send button this time only email is coming not showing the success message and loader. One more thing currently in my text fields the value=name is working as a label so I put the values again in success function but what about the text area?

Comment: Is the data reaching your 'SendMail' page or stopping before it gets there?

Comment: It is reaching successfully to the sendmail and getting the email every time when user submit form. but in second time the loader and success message is not displaying..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success: portion of your Ajax you are  using fadeOut.

I do not see anywhere that you are fading back in.

If you either remove fadeOut from the success or add fadeIn to the loading message it should work well.